# can sharepoint "lookup for single line of text" in workflow get all lists in site and its subsites?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, sub-site

this is my workflow, I have Sharepoint site and subsites and lists on there, this workflow belongs to one of the subsite so in workflow I only reach lists which is on this subsite, and my question is if there is some way to get lists on whole Sharepoint site.
 (test in picture is one of the list on subsite)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried publishing it on the site collection?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you open subsite in SharePoint Designer and create this workflow?

If that’s the case, we are not able to get top-level site lists in a subsite workflow.

As a workaround, you can use SharePoint 2013 workflow platform and use “Call Http web service” action to get top-level site lists via rest api.

Here are some reference:

[How To Enable SharePoint 2013 Workflow In SharePoint Designer 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-enable-sharepoint-2013-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/)

[Get Items from SharePoint list using Call HTTP Web Service Action (SharePoint Designer 2013)](https://zareensoomro.wordpress.com/2015/07/02/get-items-from-sharepoint-list-using-call-http-web-service-action-sharepoint-designer-2013/)